# Building qBitorrent with qt5 fails (qt4 works)

Tags: package-management, compiling, qt, qbittorrent

I want to build qBittorrent v3.4.0alpha with qt5, but I'm getting errors.

In this qBittorrent version qt5 is the default, but running `./configure --with-qt4 && make` builds it using qt4, which is working fine. But I want qt5.

I have downloaded a bunch of qt5 packages, including `qtbase5-dev` and `qttools5-dev-tools` as suggested here (https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu). The configure script seems to be finding what it is looking for:

```
checking whether Qt4 should be enabled... no
checking for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake... yes
checking for Qt5 qmake >= 5.2.0... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake
checking whether QtDBus should be enabled... yes
checking for Qt5DBus >= 5.2.0... found
```

Still I am getting errors from the compilation process:

```
compiling base/utils/misc.cpp
base/utils/misc.cpp: In function ‘QString Utils::Misc::osName()’:
base/utils/misc.cpp:647:10: error: ‘prettyProductName’ is not a member of ‘QSysInfo’
     .arg(QSysInfo::prettyProductName())
          ^
base/utils/misc.cpp:648:10: error: ‘kernelVersion’ is not a member of ‘QSysInfo’
     .arg(QSysInfo::kernelVersion())
          ^
base/utils/misc.cpp:649:10: error: ‘currentCpuArchitecture’ is not a member of ‘QSysInfo’
     .arg(QSysInfo::currentCpuArchitecture());
          ^
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Works fine on Trusty Tahr: http://www.andrews-corner.org/images/qbittorrent.png Did the compile completely fail or were there simply errors? I can write up a detailed answer with specific directions for Trusty if you like...

Comment: I'm running Trusty Tahr. I will try v3.3.3 and see if that works better. The errors stop the build process. Please give me the detailed directions, specifically which qt5 packages you have.

Comment: Done, I ran the process again on a clean VM and should run OK on your system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building `qbittorrent` against `qt5` on Trusty Tahr requires some careful preparation. First create a build area:

```
mkdir -pv $HOME/Desktop/qbittorrent_build/{qbittorrent,libtorrent-rasterbar}
```

The download all of the required dependencies with this single command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libboost-dev \
     libboost-system-dev qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev-tools python \
     geoip-database libssl-dev libgeoip-dev pkg-config
```

Then compile and install the required *newer* version of `libtorrent-rasterbar` with the following single command (agreeing with all of the `checkinstall` defaults):

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/qbittorrent_build/libtorrent-rasterbar && \
wget https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/releases/download/libtorrent-1_0_9/libtorrent-rasterbar-1.0.9.tar.gz && \
tar xvf libtorrent-rasterbar-1.0.9.tar.gz && \
cd libtorrent-rasterbar-1.0.9 && \
./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr --with-libgeoip=system && \
make && sudo checkinstall
```

**Release Version qbittorrent:**

If you wish to compile `qbittorrent` 'release' version 3.3.3 then use  the following single command (again agreeing with all of the `checkinstall` defaults):

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/qbittorrent_build/qbittorrent && \
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/qbittorrent/qbittorrent-3.3.3.tar.gz && \
tar xvf qbittorrent-3.3.3.tar.gz && cd qbittorrent-3.3.3 && \
./configure --prefix=/usr && make && \
sudo checkinstall
```

If you like then you can delete the folder `$HOME/Desktop/qbittorrent_build` although personally I would keep the files for further experimentation with the build.

Below is a screenshot of my own successful installation:

[image]

**Development Version qbittorrent:**

If however you would like to compile and install the development version of `qbittorrent`, currently 3.4.0alpha, then tun the following single command:

```
sudo apt-get install git && \
cd $HOME/Desktop/qbittorrent_build/qbittorrent && \
git clone https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent --depth 1 && \
cd qBittorrent && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && \
sudo checkinstall --pkgversion 3.4.0alpha
```

And this will install 3.4.0alpha; remember if you wish to update your git clone in the future to manipulate the `--pkgversion` option of checkinstall so you can achieve incremental upgrades. Best using the `date` command...

Below is a screenshot of the alpha version in operation:

[image]

And remember to keep all of your torrenting legal :).

Comment: Thank, but I can't really mark this as accepted since I was asking about qBittorrent v3.4.0alpha. I've been developing for qBittorrent so I want to use the latest version from the GitHub repo.  v3.3.3 installs straight away, so I suppose this alpha version was more broken than I expected.

Comment: With the risk of this turning into an XY problem, the real reason why I wanted to upgrade to qt5 was because I realized that my feature might work better as an actual tweak to the qt framework. And then I figured I should run qt 5.6 or 5.7. I wasn't able to compile qBittorrent v3.3.3 then, even using the `QT_QMAKE` environment variable. There ultimately seems to be some problem with qt-dbus, I think it's the wrong version. Maybe I'll just start a new question.

Comment: I will have a look at the alpha, I imagine that you are running this from git head?

Comment: Exactly, https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent

Comment: OK qbittorrent 3.4.0alpha compiles and runs cleanly on a fresh VM of Trusty, I have included screenshot and commandline syntax. Hops this has been useful to you. I have enjoyed having a closer look at qbittorrent :)

Comment: I created a VM too and to my surprise the compilation worked! So I went back and re-did the whole process from step one. Threw out libtorrent-rasterbar and recompiled, then did the same for qbittorrent and now it works. libtorrent's `configure` recognized that I had qbittorrent installed, so there seems to be some two-way communication there. I believe that when I originally built libtorrent I was still lacking some qt5 package, maybe that is what caused problems at the later stage. It is still weird that other combinations of qbittorrent/qt worked even with the "broken" libtorrent.

Comment: This ordeal really opened my eyes to the importance of properly purging between configurations/builds. Also, in case anyone is interested, I managed to get qt 5.7 (and 5.6) working with qbittorrent v3.4.0alpha: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt57-alpha-trusty && sudo apt-get install '^qt57.*' && source /opt/qt57/bin/qt57-env.sh`. It's probably not necessary install all the packages, but at least it wasn't enough with qt57base.

Comment: ... And that previous command need a `sudo apt-get update` after adding the PPA.